# Extjs - How do you tell proxy in store to send data just as ordinary http parameters?

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4

I do not understand how I can tell the proxy to simply submit the data as ordinary http parameters to the post-request. You could think that would be the simplest thing to do, but I just cant get my store to send anything other then xml or json to the server when CRUDing.

Please tell me I'm missing something really simple.

```
Ext.define('ObjectManager.store.Object', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'ObjectManager.model.Object',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api:{
            read: 'http://localhost/Get/',
            update: 'http://localhost/Edit/',
            create: 'http://localhost/Add/',
            delete: 'http://localhost/Delete/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'objects',
            record: 'object'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the method used by the Proxy per CRUD action can be configured with the following config:

```
actionMethods: {
    create : 'POST',
    read   : 'POST',
    update : 'POST',
    destroy: 'POST'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a store configuration that reads JSON and sends the data as POST. I believe the key is in the writer config: "encode: true"

```
/* Data store */
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'categoryStore',
    model: 'Model.Category',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,

    groupField: 'CategoryParent',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '',
            create: '',
            update: '',
            destroy: ''
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }, 
        writer: {
            root: 'data',
            encode: true,
            allowSingle: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will only send the json into the parameter "data" instead. I don't want json or xml, if my object is User(FirstName, LastName) I want the proxy to make a POST-request and submit the parameters FirstName and LastName.

Comment: @Alex try removing root config from reader and writer, Then move this proxy config to model instead of store